# How do I print a true statement if only 1 of 3 inputs is a positive number?

Tags: kotlin, operation, relational, false-positive

This is what I am currently using.

```kotlin
fun main() {
   val num1 = readLine()!!.toInt()
   val num2 = readLine()!!.toInt()
   val num3 = readLine()!!.toInt()
   
   println(num1 >= 1 || num2 >= 1 || num3 >= 1)
}
```

Comment: You mean _exactly_ one of the  three numbers is positive? Or _at least_ one number?

Comment: The statement can only be true if only one number is positive. If two numbers are positive, it's automatically false.

Comment: OR for the first 2 and XNOR for the result of the first 2 with the third https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/logic-gate-AND-OR-XOR-NOT-NAND-NOR-and-XNOR

Comment: `fun main()
 {
   val num1 = readLine()!!.toInt()
   val num2 = readLine()!!.toInt()
   val num3 = readLine()!!.toInt()
   
  
   println(num1 >= 1 OR num2 >= 1 XNOR num3 >= 1 )
  
}
`

Answer (score 4):

One way is to make a list, and [`count`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/count.html)

```
// prints true if exactly one of the numbers is positive
println(listOf(num1, num2, num3).count { it > 0 } == 1)
```

If you don't want to create the list, the logic is equivalent to `(num1 > 0) XOR (num2 > 0) XOR (num3 > 0)`, except the case when all three are positive. We can replace XORs with `!=`, and handle the edge case, like this:

```
println(((num1 > 0) != (num2 > 0) != (num3 > 0)) &&
        !(num1 > 0 && num2 > 0 && num3 > 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , it will mean if any of this number positive number then it will return true. You can't go from num1 > 1 . because one is already positive number , in your code you checking if num1 is bigger that 1 . But your questions is about positive number , then use num1 > 0 . Done!

```
fun main() {
       val num1 = readLine()!!.toInt()
       val num2 = readLine()!!.toInt()
       val num3 = readLine()!!.toInt()
       
       println(num1 > 0 || num2 > 0 || num3 > 0)
    }
```